# point in-time recovery in PostgreSQL for windows

Tags: postgresql

I am using `archive_cleanup_command` in my `recovery.conf` file. When I start PostgreSQL server I am getting FATAL and postgres is not starting.

```
FATAL:  syntax error in file "recovery.conf" line 4, near token "'"
```

showing in pg_log

`recovery.conf`:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres  password=postgres'
restore_command = 'copy  "D:\\Program Files\\WAL\\%f" "%p" '
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup "D:\\Program Files\\WAL" %r'
trigger_file = 'standby.stop'
recovery_target_timeline='latest'
```

Comment: Can any one help me on above question.

Comment: You only asked an hour ago... and the question was nearly illegible too. The `recovery.conf` looks reasonable as-written (unless I missed something), are you sure that's the full, exact `recovery.conf` exactly as installed?

Comment: yes. Please archive cleanup command is correct or not

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with it from what you've shown above. I might just be missing something.

Comment: I am not able to find what is missing one.

Comment: Nobody know the answer for above question?

Comment: Shall i delete the above question?

Comment: Well, I can't see what's wrong, so either I'm blind, there's an issue I don't understand, or what you pasted doesn't correspond in some way to what you're actually running. Either way, I don't think I can help and nobody else has stepped up.